# Interesting Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, function-and-relation-composition

I was messing with sequences defined recursively in terms of the previous two terms and I came across the sequence
$$P_n=4P_{n-2}-P_{n-1}$$
I have been trying to find two seeds $P_1$ and $P_2$ so that no value of $P_n$ is negative, and I haven't been able to do it. I have not yet tried writing an explicit formula in terms of the seeds, but it will be messy and inelegant if I do. Is there another way to find two such seeds or prove their nonexistence?
Thanks!

Comment: $0,0$ works....

Comment: The closed form isn't bad...you just solve $x^2=4-x$ and get two solutions $\frac 12(-1\pm \sqrt {17})$.  One solution is about $-2.56$ and the other is about $1.56$ so the negative one always dominates eventually (unless it vanishes completely).

Comment: Well yeah, I noticed 0,0, but I was looking for nontrivial answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution of this recursion is $a r_1^n + b r_2^n$ where $r_1 =  (-1-\sqrt{17})/2$ and $r_2 = (-1+\sqrt{17})/2$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2 + x -4$.  Since $r_1 < 0 < r_2$ and $|r_1|>r_2$, the only way to have all terms positive is to have $a=0$ and $b > 0$.  Thus you want
$P_2 = P_1 r_2$ with $P_1 > 0$.